# How to access the "Value" in a .mat file without knowing the name?

Tags: matlab, opencv, mat-file

I need to load in a .mat file and extract the data. The .mat file will always store one variable with a "Name" and a "Value":

**'name' <1024x1280x20 uint8>** (for example)

To access the data, I currently have to know the variable name, so I do something like:

```
matfile = 'somematfile.mat';
load(matfile);
if exist('name','var')
    data=name;
end
```

I'm wondering how to do this without knowing what the variable name is in the MAT File.

Cheers,
Sean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `M=load(matfile);`, then you get a struct with all variables in the matfile. Use `f=fieldnames(M)` to get a list of all variables in the struct and `M.(f{1})` to access the first variable (assuming you have only 1)

Comment: thanks! worked perfectly. I was actually experimenting around with using whos(), but fieldnames() is much more direct.